# Kendo UI not working on Windows Server 2016

Tags: kendo-ui, windows-server-2016

We have a product that uses Kendo UI on the front end. On a Windows Server 2016 box we were getting some odd results, random parts of it not working.

We knew that the machine had 'IE Enhanced Security Configuration' switched on but the site had been added to the trusted list. There were no console errors, no missing files in the network trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because something in the product was resulting in navigation to 'about:blank'. We only found out by accident as another Windows Server 2016 box was reporting errors in a popup, this one wasn't.

Once we added about:blank to the trusted sites list then the web site came back to life